# glGenVertexArrays not available in c++

Tags: c++, opengl

As i have already programmed with opengl on java I tried to switch to c++ using Visual Studio 2015 Community

I currently have opengl version 4.5 installed (cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION))

I normally have included all libraries I need for programming but for some reason there is no "glGenVertexArrays" and "glGenBufferArrays" available

Could it be that I forgot a library?

Comment: Did you use GLEW (OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library) or something similar?

Comment: What do you mean by "not available"?

Comment: What [OpenGL Loading Library](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) are you using?

Comment: I am using GLFW for the window

Comment: I used opengl32 and glfw3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On windows, the default header files and libs do only support OpenGL 1.1. When you want to use a higher version, you have to load the extensions manually or use an extension loading library like [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) (which I would recommend).